# Can anyone produce a minimal working example of listings in Beamer?

Tags: code, python, debugging, inline, examples

I'm trying out the solution in : [Lstlisting Python](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436640/lstlisting-python)

but in Beamer.

And no matter what I write, it throws me like a thousand errors:

[image]

I thoroughly checked. There is no missing }

My code is literally (after I have all the correct packages as indicated in the url above)

```
\begin{frame} \begin{lstlisting}    do nothing. \end{lstlisting} \end{frame}
```

can someone produce a minimal working example so I can try to replicate?

Btw I have no luck with minted because I'm missing some pygm package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `fragile` option to `frame`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, keywordstyle=\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile] % <---
\frametitle{Example of \texttt{listings} code}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
if x==0:
    print(x)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Fragile seems to be the silver bullet in 99% of these mysterious errors.